# Remove Search Label in DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to remove label of Search Box and increase the size of box in `dataTable`. This code works fine but a `dataTable` warning message always shows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datatableit").dataTable({initComplete : function(){
        $("#datatableit_filter").detach().appendTo('#newSearch');
    });

    $("#datatableit").dataTable({"oLanguage":{"sSearch":""}});
});
```

Comment: What is the warning message?

Comment: fix grammer, formatting

Comment: @Ouroborus, fix grammer? That's the funniest comment today :), thank you for making my day!

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Har! My bad, that was supposed to be a edit reason =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize table only once. Use the code below:

```
$("#datatableit").dataTable({
   "initComplete": function(){
      $("#datatableit_filter").detach().appendTo('#newSearch');
   },
   "language": { "search": "" }
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/kfvLxnut/) for code and demonstration.